# How to dynamically update a listviewitem through code

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview and would like to update the text of one of the columns for a specific listviewitem (row).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without any context because there are so many ways you could populate your list!

The generic answer is you bind your list to a collection view which itself binds its source to your viewmodel (or you bind directly to your viewmodel if you don't need `CollectionView` features).

When you want to modify your list, you make sure you raise a [modification notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on your property, and XAML binding will take care of updating everything.

It is really basic stuff on dependency property and binding, you should read more about this topic. [MVVM-light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) is a very light framework that allows you to take care of all kinds of binding-related issues with a very clean and neat flavor. You will also find some very good self-explanatory webcasts from the author of the website about all those topics.

Comment: Most people probably do not use DPs in VMs.

Comment: Yeah right, I was too elliptic here. I edited it to the proper `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism.